# Problema con localhost:8080

Tags: java, http, postman, localhost, error-403

Buenos/as dias/noches colegas, estoy teniendo un problema con el localhost8080. Estoy realizando un backend en java con jwt para un proyecto de la facultad y al correr el programa en teoria funciona bien y se conecta con la respectiva base de datos pero cuando quiero ingresar a mi localhost:8080 me aparece "Se ha denegado el acceso al localhost y error 403, y si intento realizar la peticion por postman tambien me tira el error 403. Alguien sabe por qué se genera este error o como corregirlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Lectura sugerida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour 3. ¿Se está ejecutando en http o en https?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, gracias por la bienvenida y tendré en cuenta la lectura sugerida. Disculpa la demora en mi respuesta, se ejecuta solamente en HTTP

Comment: Normal, cada quien responde cuando puede y ya~ por otro lado, ¿podrías poner lo que tienes del backend para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario?

Comment: Hola, paso un git en el que tengo el ejemplo, esta hecho igual que el proyecto, supuestamente funciona pero me da el mismo error. Fijate la conexion a la base de datos porque le saque mis credenciales. https://github.com/Joaquin-Agraso/PruebaJWT

Comment: El controlador dice `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`, estás llamando al `localhost:8080`. ¿Entiendes a qué se refiere con Cross Origin?

Comment: Si el CrossOrigins se utiliza para linkearlo con el frontend en Angular(el cual corre en el puerto 4200), en ese caso que es de ejemplo no es necesario que esté ahí, pero si lo comentas o lo sacas no afecta en el funcionamiento en este caso

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacer la llamada desde el Angular por http desde el puerto 4200? (Si lo has hecho y te parece redundante la pregunta, edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que has intentado).

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error del lado del cliente que tiene que ver con las restricciones, es decir que tenes que fijarte el tema de los permisos, seguramente en el servidor de Apache.

Una cosa mas, por lo que veo parece que esta trabajando con datos, por lo que mas adelante tambien vas a tener que ver el tema de como manejar los permisos a la base de datos, en caso de que un futuro quieras hacer un sistema para que los usuarios puedan dejar sus datos, etc.

Comment: Hola, paso un git en el que tengo el ejemplo, esta hecho igual que el proyecto, supuestamente funciona pero me da el mismo error. Fijate la conexion a la base de datos porque le saque mis credenciales. https://github.com/Joaquin-Agraso/PruebaJWT